# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:Comparable (PlanePQ is in unnamed module of loader 'app'

Tags: java

Airport file

```
        
    public void addPlane(PlanePQ p) {
        landingPQ.add(p);
    }
```

TestDriver

```
  landingPQ.addPlane(p1);
```

These are the files in my folder

```
.
├── AirportLandingPQ.java
├── PlanePQ.java
└── TestDriver.java

0 directories, 3 files
```

This here is the error i bump into

```
     cd /home/sk33p34/Documents/Nkatha ; /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -cp /home/sk33p34/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/baef85568ba24a4b046e5fe2b564d599/redhat.java/jdt_ws/Nkatha_9f965eb7/bin TestDriver 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class PlanePQ cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (PlanePQ is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:658)
        at java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:654)
        at java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:345)
        at java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:326)
        at AirportLandingPQ.addPlane(AirportLandingPQ.java:17)
        at TestDriver.main(TestDriver.java:23)
```

[The code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTsuC.png)

Comment: i could send a picture of the code for both the files ..

Comment: oopsie.. already edited.. lemme del but its kinda clear... any way to get help haha

Comment: thank you i changed the comparator on PlanePQ and added a method stub at the bottom worked